# Django - django templating and tags

Tags: django, inheritance, frontend, templating

I'm new in Django framework and I'm trying to follow step to step the official django project's documentation.
In templating i have a file HTML called `base.html` and following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>{ % block title %}{ % endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My helpful timestamp site</h1>
{ % block content %}{ % endblock %}
{ % block footer %}
<hr>
<p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
{ % endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and other file called 'hour_ahead.html" with following code:

```
{ % extends "base.html" %}
{ % block title %}Hours ahead{ % endblock %}
{ % block content %}
<p>In {{ plus.offset }} Hours. It will be {{plus.dt}} .</p>
{ % endblock %}
```

Inside view.py, this is the method that implements the template:

```
def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    offset = int(offset)
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    c = {'plus':{'offset':offset, 'dt':dt}}
    return render_to_response('hour_ahead.html',c)
```

Same all correct, but when I want view this page with Chrome, I'm watching this:

> { % extends "base.html" %} { % block title %}Hours ahead{ % endblock
>   %} { % block content %} In 1 Hours. It will be Nov. 12, 2012, 12:21
>   a.m. .
>
> { % endblock %}

My question is: How can I hide all tags `{% ...%}` in front end? and Because Don't print it the "hours ahead" title ?

thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the space between { and %